# Remove space above inset grouped UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a table view controller with a navigation bar. My table view is an inset grouped table view, and i have headers for each section. I'm trying to remove the space above the header of the table view. Here is my table view:
[image]
How can I do that?

I've tried:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.1
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who's still searching for an answer. That padding is caused by the UITableView's own header. This can be set with the *tableHeaderView* attribute. So it will look like this:

```
let tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 100), style: .grouped)
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: CGFloat.leastNonzeroMagnitude))
```

Settings the *height* to zero will cause the default height behaviour and not the actual size to be 0.

Comment: The solution above worked for me. My section header height was `.leastNormalMagnitude` for section 0 because I don't want a title on the first section, but `.automaticDimesnsion` for the other headers because the other sections have titles.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the method viewForHeaderInSection from your tableviewcontroller
It should help you.

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?`

With this method, it looks like

[image]

And without

[image]

Answer (score 0):

from iOS 13.0

```swift
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return .leastNonzeroMagnitude
    }
```

seems works for me.